# Ерепениться и хорохориться

Tags: этимология

Вспомнился номер из КВН:
*"- Да ты еще и хорохоришься?!

- Это я хорохорюсь? Да я вообще никогда не хорохорюсь.

- Да ты еще и ерепенишься?!!!

- Ладно, признаю, было немного в детстве - хорохорился, но чтобы ерепениться?!

- Да ты еще и гнушаешься ерепениться?"*
Слово "ерепениться" тут уже, кажется, обсуждалось, но вот меня еще интересует происхождение слова "хорохориться" (храбриться).

Answer (score 2):

хорохо́риться хорохо́ря "тот, кто хорохорится", наряду с ерохо́риться – то же, под влиянием слова еро́ха "упрямец, спорщик", еро́шиться. Первонач. *хоrхоr-, по-видимому, исконнослав. (Торбьёрнссон 2, 28), но едва ли связано чередованием гласных с шерша́вый, шорох, вопреки Ильинскому (ИОРЯС 20, 4, 173). Разумеется, не от названия столицы монголов Каракорум, вопреки Голубинскому у Горяева, Доп. I, 53. Ср. хорхо́ра.(Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс. М. Р. Фасмер.) 
Яркая стилистическая окрашенность этих слов создает юмористический эффект. Лексическим богатством русского языка  эффективно пользуются юмористы. Представьте себе, для сравнения: стилей, что процитированная вами миниатюра звучала бы так:
Так ты еще и храбришься, задорно горячишься, держишь себя  заносчиво? 
Так ты еще и, раздражаясь, упрямо, с горячностью противишься чему-либо?
Ладно, признаю, было немного в детстве - задорно горячился, но чтобы с горячностью противишься чему-либо?

Answer (score 1):

Относительно ЕРЕПЕНИТЬСЯ, мне видится связь со словом АРАПНИК - *длинный охотничий кнут с пеньковым, волосяным или шёлковым навоем, размещённый на коротком кнутовище. Первоначально применялся в псовой охоте для порсканья зайцев*. Есть и прилагательное АРАПИСТЫЙ, - Большой толковый словарь: *АРАПИСТЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -пист, -а, -о. Разг.
Действующий на арапа; бесстыдный, наглый (о человеке). < Араписто, нареч. Действовать а.* Вообще, в разговорной речи первоначальное значение слова может расплываться и менять содержание смысла. Слово ЕРЕПЕНИТЬСЯ один из таких примеров. ЕРЕПЕНИТЬСЯ может употребляться  и так, и этак (относительно значения), стабильно сохраняя только негативно-ругательный оттенок.